# Build color scale from numeric values in python

Tags: python, colors, heatmap

I need a method to build a color scale from a numeric variable, for example from blue through black to red, for further use on geo heat maps and other things. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using `matplotlib` and its built in colormaps - see https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html